# Как реализовать удаление одинаковых слов из строки?

Tags: c++, строки

Моей задачей является удаление одинаковых слов из введённого пользователем предложения. Я реализовал это в СИ, но вышло мягко говоря много. Мне же необходима реализация в C++ через string, либо любым другим удобным для вас способом.

Слова разделены пробелами. Знаков препинания нет

Comment: Удаление должно сохранять порядок слов? Строка длинная?

Comment: порядок не имеет значения. строка не более 200 символов

Comment: Используем `set` - и все в порядке. Слова при этом расположатся в новом предложении по алфавиту - это не пугает? :) Да, у вас ничего не сказано о знаках препинания...

Comment: Нет, не пугает) Просто я с С++ не знаком( А set это как раз С++. Знаков препинания нет вообще

Comment: Ну, у вас же и тэг С++... :)

Comment: Ладно, буду пытаться реализовать, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтоб покороче - [вот так примерно](https://ideone.com/qzwRRC)...

```
int main()
{
    string in;
    getline(cin,in);
    set<string> st;
    istringstream is(in);
    while(is >> in) st.insert(in);
    for(auto s: st) cout << s << " ";
}
```

Comment: а в си вышло в виде 5 функций..... спасибо!!!!!! иду учить с++)

Comment: Замечательное решение - учить С++ :) Если ответ устроил - то птичка слева означает его принятие..

Comment: Там можно отметить только через 5 минут, я жду)

Comment: Перейдите по ссылке - щелкните на "вот так примерно" в ответе - там полный текст со всеми библиотеками. Даже лишняя есть - `<iomanip>` тут не использована.